# Start a branch from two branches

Tags: git

I have a git branch which would start from two branches. How do I do this without use of merge or rebase and merge the two parent branches at time of branch creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have to use `git merge` (or similar) at some point. I'd start a new branch from the tip of one of the parents, then merge the other one in:

```
$ git checkout -b child parent1
$ git merge parent2
```

Comment: This is what I did, Thank you for verifying. :)

Answer (score -2):

You are asking to write a word without using any letters, that's impossible.

Please read more documentation to understand better the tool you are using...